# Combining 2 Tables in SQL and add a new column to a Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables.
CustomerDetails table has columns ID, UUID, Name, Age.
FavoriteCustomers table has columns ID, UUID

CustomerDetails Table will have a lot of entries say 10000 rows. while FavoriteCustomers Table has very few entries. In CustomerDetails Table, ID and UUID form the combined unique ID.

Now I want the result to be combined row columns like below with a where clause.

ID, UUID, Name, Age, isFavorite WHERE Age is > 30

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using. The answer may heavily depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DBMS that support some kind of a boolean type you can use an `EXISTS` clause or an `IN` clause.

```
select
  id, uuid, name, age,
  (id, uuid) in (select id, uuid from favoritecustomers) as is_favorite
from customerdetails
where age > 30;
```

Comment: Hi downvoter. Care to explain your whys? Don't you like `EXISTS` and `IN`? Don't you like booleans? Don't you like working with tuples? What is it? I think my answer is the straight-forward solution to the task.

Comment: I don't know why my answer was downvoted as well. I could not find the solution you provided anywhere else. I searched nearly 20 SO questions for the solution. Stack overflow has to force people to give comments when they are downvoting the answer or question. Now I don't know why they have downvoted my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either a sub-query or, as in the example below, a `LEFT JOIN` and check for a `NULL` value from the join.

```
select cd.ID, cd. UUID, cd.Name, cd.Age, 
   case when fc.ID is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as isFavorite
from CustomerDetails cd
left join FavoriteCustomers fc
on fc.ID = cd.ID
where cd.Age > 30;
```